# Displaying SQLite Data In DataGridView VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

I am using sqlite database and using vb.net i am trying to print some rows in datagridview. I use the following code:

```
Public Sub LoadUsername()
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=info.sqlite"
    Dim nSQL As String = "SELECT Name From employee"
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(nSQL, con)
                con.Open()
                Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)

                    Console.WriteLine(da)
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    dt = ds.Tables(0)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        ListBox1.ValueMember = "Name"
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName"
        ListBox1.DataSource = dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

but when i execute or compile this program, it shows me **System.Data.DataRowView** in the field where name should be. please check the image. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: a ListBox is not a DataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `FullName` column in your datatable yet that's what you're trying to bind the display to. Change the `DisplayMember` to Name as it should work correctly.

`System.Data.DataRow` is just the default `ToString` implementation as it cant find your fullname property.